# Sum of independent Brownian Motions: $\sqrt{a}dW_{1,t}+\sqrt{b}dW_{2,t}=\sqrt{a+b}dW_{3,t}$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider two stochastic differential equations:

a)
$$
dX=\sqrt{a}dW_{1,t}+\sqrt{b}dW_{2,t}
$$

b)
$$
dX=\sqrt{a+b}dW_{3,t}
$$

where $W_{1,t},W_{2,t},W_{3,t}$ are independent brownian motions. **Do these two equations give the same dynamics?**

Since the distribution of $\sqrt{a}W_{1,t}+\sqrt{b}W_{2,t}$ is equivalent to the distribution of $W_{1,at}+W_{2,bt}$, which is also equivalent to the distribution of $W_{3,(a+b)t}$, and eventually that is equivalent to the distribution of $\sqrt{a+b}W_{3,t}$, can we simply say that those two equations are also identical?

Comment: Same dynamics? Yes. As you noted, the two equations imply the same finite-dimensional distributions. Identical equations? I'd say no, for the simple reason that the two equations are, well, different. There's more than one notion of sameness for stochastic processes, which you might want to look up.

Comment: @AddSup Many thanks! So in terms of the distribution of the random variable $X_t$, both equations will give us the same result for the same $t$, given that the initial values are the same? Intuitively the first equation has two independent random noises, while the second equation seems to have coupled them up...but still they are equivalent in distribution.

Comment: Yes. The sum of two independent normal random variables is also normal. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Independent_random_variables